# arrray_udiff makes my array disappear

Tags: php, arrays

I am running a number of comparisons between two arrays of objects using `array_udiff()` in Codeigniter. Each comparison is run twice, once 'a' against 'b' and once 'b' against 'a'.

Most of the comparisons are working just fine but one is not. When I inspect the arrays before they are passed to the function they are both full of data but when inspecting the arrays within the udiff callback function one is full of data, the other one is empty making it impossible to carry out any comparisons.

```
$comparison    = 'test2';
$diff_function = $comparison . '_function';

echo $was; //full
echo $is;  //full

$arrdiff1 = array_udiff($was, $is, array('templates', $diff_function)));
$arrdiff2 = array_udiff($is, $was, array('templates', $diff_function)));


test1_function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->string1, $b->string1);
    //works: returns comparison as expected
}

test2_function($a, $b) {
    echo $a; //full
    echo $b; //empty
    //comparison will result in all elements from $a being returned
    return strcmp($a->string2, $b->string2);
}
```

Any suggestions as to what might be going on here or how I might go about debugging this would be most welcome.

Comment: the code itself seems to be invalid. The third argument of `array_udiff` should be a callback function, not an array. the callbacks themselves should be preceded by the `function` keyword.Also, please post the content of both arrays ($was and $is)

Comment: @Matanya note that's PHP 5.2 so no anonymous functions, also third parameter should be a callback not necesserily a function ;)

Comment: @Matanya in Codeigniter, when calling a callback function in a native PHP function that is the correct syntax. It is in the form array(controller, method)

Comment: This problem is likely more related to the data you have than your code. *Additionally* (most likely not the cause of your problem), test1_function and test2_function should be static methods of the `templates` class. Which make me think that you might want to turn on error reporting to the very highest level and take care of all warnings and notices to debug your issue: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/160969/